# How can i add extra attribute to Django ManyToOneRel?

Tags: python, django

I want do something programmatically, so i have this models:

models.py:

```
class Treatment(TimeElement, models.Model):
  code = models.CharField(verbose_name="Código", max_length=50, blank=True)
  ...

class Prescription(TimeElement, models.Model):
  treatment = fields.CustomForeignKey('Treatment', verbose_name="Tratamiento", related_name='prescription_treatment', on_delete=models.CASCADE, invers=False)
```

With the parameter `invers` in `CustomForeignKey` I know if in PrescriptionModelForm I have to build the form only with the treatment identifier relation or build all the TreatmentModelForm, `code` and additional fields.

I want to know if i access the relation from Treatment i have a ManyToOneRel with this attribute `prescription_treatment` to build only one PrescriptionModelForm or Django Formset with various PrescriptionModelForms

Anybody could help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Django doesn't have a ManyToOne Field, for ManyToOne like relations use ForeignKey

Comment: Yes, i know, Django builds a ManyToOneRel from behind, what I want is to know if that relation is simple or not, to build a form or a formset.